# Activated Route Angular does not bring data from mongodb

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Activated Route Angular to get an actor with his movies, I have a list of actors, where each actor has an Activated Route link to the details with his movies.

In my service I am using

```
getActor(_id:String): Observable<Actorpelicula>{
    const url = `${this.URL_ACT}/${_id}`;

    return this.http.get<Actorpelicula>(url)
}
```

In the component

```
getActor():void{
    const _id = this.rutas.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id');
    this.peliculaService.getActor(_id)
        .subscribe(actor => this.actor = actor);
}
```

From my controller I am using this query that works, but it does not bring me all the details that I need in the query

```
peliculaCtrl.getActor = async(req, res) =>{
    const actor = await Actores.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
    res.json(actor);
}
```

I return a document with the structure:

```
{
  "_id": "5dc0365e0b2c0c479cb3fba3",
  "name": "Keanu Reeves",
  "description": "es un actor y músico canadiense-estadounidense, nacido en el Líbano. Dedicado a la actuación, tiene entre su repertorio las comedias de la franquicia de Bill y Ted (1989–1991); los thrillers de acción Point Break (1991), Speed (1994) y la franquicia John Wick (2014–2019); el thriller psicológico The Devil's Advocate (1997); el thriller sobrenatural Constantine (2005); y la serie de ciencia ficción y acción The Matrix (1999-2003). También ha participado en películas dramáticas como Dangerous Liaisons (1988), My Own Private Idaho (1991) y Little Buddha (1993), así como en la película de terror y romance Bram Stoker's Dracula (1992).",
  "height": "1.86",
  "birth": "1964-09-02T05:00:00.000Z",
  "years": 55,
  "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/tq/image/upload/v1572888170/cineencasa/actores/bOlYWhVuOiU6azC4Bw6zlXZ5QTC.jpg",
  "__v": 0
}
```

This new query has the necessary details that I need

```
peliculaCtrl.peliculasActor = async(req,res) =>{

const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

const peliculaActor = await Actores.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: ObjectId(req.params.id)
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "peliculas",
          localField: "name",
          foreignField: "cast",
          as: "peliculas"
        }
   },
   { $project: { name: 1 ,description: 1, height:1, birth:1, years:1, image:1} }
 ])

 res.json(peliculaActor);
}
```

If I make the request to the route it returns me

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5dc0365e0b2c0c479cb3fba3",
    "name": "Keanu Reeves",
    "description": "es un actor y músico canadiense-estadounidense, nacido en el Líbano. Dedicado a la actuación, tiene entre su repertorio las comedias de la franquicia de Bill y Ted (1989–1991); los thrillers de acción Point Break (1991), Speed (1994) y la franquicia John Wick (2014–2019); el thriller psicológico The Devil's Advocate (1997); el thriller sobrenatural Constantine (2005); y la serie de ciencia ficción y acción The Matrix (1999-2003). También ha participado en películas dramáticas como Dangerous Liaisons (1988), My Own Private Idaho (1991) y Little Buddha (1993), así como en la película de terror y romance Bram Stoker's Dracula (1992).",
    "height": "1.86",
    "birth": "1964-09-02T05:00:00.000Z",
    "years": 55,
    "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/tq/image/upload/v1572888170/cineencasa/actores/bOlYWhVuOiU6azC4Bw6zlXZ5QTC.jpg"
  }
]
```

But in the DOM I get the empty fields, I think it is because of the structure in which the document returns the query, the only thing I can show is that using `Actors.findOne({_ id: req.params.id})` me returns the document in `{...}` and with `Actores.aggregate ([])` returns the document `[{...}]`

I hope you can help me friends

Comment: What do you ask? What is the problem? Do you want to return an actor and his movies from your api? Is this what you ask?

Comment: Hi, how to get the query data with aggregate using activatedRoute ?